# Sails.js with skipper: check if file input were empty before starting upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm using Sails 11.1 and skipper 0.5.5.
I have a form to create an article in my app. An image can be attached to an article, so there is an input file.

I would like to check, server-side, if this input file was empty, before trying to start upload.

Is it possible, and if yes, how can I do this?

I tried to check `req.files`, or `req.files.photo` ("photo" is the input name) and `req.body.photo`, but they are always undefined, even if there is a file.
`req.file('photo')` is always defined, so I can't check it.

Just a note: when the input is filled with a file, the upload works.

Thanks in advance.

PS: this question can also be found [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/92), on the skipper GitHub issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only working solution I found while working on this a few weeks back was to upload the file(s) and then see if any file had been uploaded.

```
    req.file(inputname).upload({
        dirname: targetLocation,
        maxBytes: 2*1024*1024
    },
    function (err, uploadedFiles) {
        // do stuff with uploadedFiles
    });
```

I'm not sure why your `req.file(inputname)` returns `null` even when a file is uploaded.

Importantly, note that calling `req.file()` is tricky. I had used it to determine the file size, extension and so on initially. Seemed like a good way to avoid uploading anything at all if it were irrelevant. However, if you don't follow that call with an `upload()` call in 4.5 seconds (default), Node crashes with an ETIMEDOUT error. I had a hard time figuring that out and haven't complained about the above method ever since.

Comment: Yes, I knew this solution, but I was wondering if I could check if this input file was empty, as the others ^^ Thanks for your fast and good answer.

And I noticed this Node crash :x

"I'm not sure why your req.file(inputname) returns null even when a file is uploaded." It's the opposite: it always return an object.